# gluPickMatrix code from Mesa

Tags: c, opengl

I was studying some OpenGL codes and I found the Mesa code for the gluPickMatrix function:

```
void gluPickMatrix(GLdouble x, GLdouble y, GLdouble width, GLdouble height, 
GLint viewport[4])
{
 GLfloat m[16];
 GLfloat sx, sy;
 GLfloat tx, ty;

 sx = viewport[2] / width;
 sy = viewport[3] / height;
 tx = (viewport[2] + 2.0 * (viewport[0] - x)) / width;
 ty = (viewport[3] + 2.0 * (viewport[1] - y)) / height;

 #define M(row, col) m[col*4+row]
  M(0, 0) = sx;
  M(0, 1) = 0.0;
  M(0, 2) = 0.0;
  M(0, 3) = tx;
  M(1, 0) = 0.0;
  M(1, 1) = sy;
  M(1, 2) = 0.0;
  M(1, 3) = ty;
  M(2, 0) = 0.0;
  M(2, 1) = 0.0;
  M(2, 2) = 1.0;
  M(2, 3) = 0.0;
  M(3, 0) = 0.0;
  M(3, 1) = 0.0;
  M(3, 2) = 0.0;
  M(3, 3) = 1.0;
 #undef M

 glMultMatrixf(m);
}
```

My doubt in this case is with the M macro and the 'col*4+row' operation. This equation, as I understand, is to obtain the indexes of the pick matrix and then assign them values.

Is this macro a better approach than simply using m[0] = something?

Is it faster? or more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not faster in any way, the compiler will see the expanded code (the preprocessor expands the macros before the compiler gets at it).

It's just a convenience to save typing few characters, and make the code more readable - hardcoding the equivalent constants would be much less clear.

Comment: any coder competent in 3D graphics and homogenous coordinates should cope trivially with `m[0] .. m[15]`

Comment: What people can "cope with" and what is easy to read are two different things.