# opengl glRenderMode not changing mode

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to change the render mode for selection using `glRenderMode`, below is the code I use to do this.

```
 glSelectBuffer(size, buffer);
 int before = glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);
 std::cout << "before:" << before << std::endl;
 GLint mode;
 glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDER_MODE, &mode);i
 std::cout << "mode:" << mode << std::endl;
 std::cout << "gl_select:" << GL_SELECT << std::endl;
 std::cout << "gl_render:" << GL_RENDER << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
before: 0
mode:7168
gl_select:7170
gl_render:7168
```

Which tells me that the mode is not changing, since by default it is in `GL_RENDER`

edit: changed code to verify it returns 0 before glRenderMode, as per @Axalo comment.

Also I noticed that running `glGetError()` before the above block of code returns `0`

But the following code will give me `1282` error code again

```
glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
```

From the docs for [glRendMode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRenderMode.xml#errors), possible cause is runnning in between `glBegin` and `glEnd` but I do not have a call to `glBegin`

EDIT
opengl picking is depricated in 3.1. I am using opgenl version >3.1 therefore this is not working.

Comment: What does `glGetError()` return?

Comment: `glGetError()` returns `1282`

Comment: Make sure it returns 0 **before** `glRenderMode` and 1282 **afterwards**. See [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRenderMode.xml#errors) for more information.

Comment: GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glSelectBuffer is called while the render mode is GL_SELECT, or if glRenderMode is called with argument GL_SELECT before glSelectBuffer is called at least once.

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu do you know by heart if `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`  would also be thrown for cards/drivers/profiles not supporting picking anymore?

Comment: A lot of functionalities of OpenGL are deprecated and still supported. This should not be any different. I tested your program and it works fine here. It is possible that your graphic card driver doesn't support this functionality.